# How to link a button to a Youtube user in Youtube app

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube

I found this code to link to a specific video in youtube app but how can I show the youtube user?

I used this code to show a specific video:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZH30T99MaM";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

http://www.youtube.com/user/username

and

http://www.youtube.com/channel/channelname+some varibales

Does anyone know how to do this?

and what if the user havent got the youtube app which is available afte ios6?

Comment: can't you just set the stringURL to the user url?  `stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/user/username"`?

Comment: @MasterRazer : Did you find solution for this? I also want to load channel in youtube app...

Comment: @FahimParkar Well actually no. Istead I used a Webview and loaded the profile within my app. Sorry if that can`t help you.

Comment: @MasterRazer : Ahh... its ok... right now I am doing the same thing ;) but looking for a way where I can open channel if youtube app...

Comment: @FahimParkar I`m annoyed of the youtube app. They do nothing with it. There is actually just the possibility to show a playlist or a specific video...I`m tired of this. Hope your solution works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All possible links within the app are displayed [here](http://krish.codeworth.com/development/ios-development-2/iphone-2/url-schemes/). Opening a specific channel within the YouTube App from yours is not supported with a URL link.

Comment: well but those links are just for a specific video. I want to load a user not a video. I would be happy if you could show me the code I need.